# Error:(63, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile'

Tags: java, android

I want your help. please i help.

> Error:(63, 0) Cannot set the value of read-only property 'outputFile' for ApkVariantOutputImpl_Decorated{apkData=Main{type=MAIN, fullName=debug, filters=[]}} of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.api.ApkVariantOutputImpl. Open File

```
applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def file = output.outputFile
        output.outputFile = new File(file.parent, "kickmaterial-" + defaultConfig.versionName + ".apk")
    }
}
```

android version is 3.0.1
please your help.

Answer (score 1):

Start from gradle plugin 3.0, you can't use `each()` as in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#variant_output) says:

> Using the Variant API to manipulate variant outputs is broken with the
>   new plugin. It still works for simple tasks, such as changing the APK
>   name during build time, as shown below:
>
> ```
> // If you use each() to iterate through the variant objects,
> // you need to start using all(). That's because each() iterates
> // through only the objects that already exist during configuration time—
> // but those object don't exist at configuration time with the new model.
> // However, all() adapts to the new model by picking up object as they are
> // added during execution.
>
> android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
>     variant.outputs.all {
>         outputFileName = "${variant.name}-${variant.versionName}.apk"
>     }
> }
> ```

---

So, you need to make your block code like the following:

```
android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.all {
        outputFileName = "$kickmaterial-${variant.versionName}.apk"
    }
}
```